# Device aware multifactor authentication with Citrix environment?

Tags: authentication, citrix, xenapp, netscaler

There are many services that advertise themselves as providing multifactor authentication for Citrix. But, most seem to require the additional generated passcode every time.  Are there any that can require the password once per device, like Google's 2 step verification?  So that once a device is registered, it only needs username/password at that point.

Components of this environment:

- NetScaler Access Gateway
- Storefront
- XenApp

I anticipate it would be the access gateway providing the mutlifactor aspect.

Comment: Citrix what? Citrix is a company, not a product. I assume XenApp, but you have the NetScalar tag in there which is a load balancer so I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Good point, I indicated it's a Citrix Environment in the title, but didn't detail what was included in that.  I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that most IT environments that require 2-factor authentication are doing it for security compliance reasons, which generally *always* requires the use of both factors for every authentication.

Comment: I see that the Azure Multi-factor server (formerly PhoneFactor) has the notion of caching, am investigating that.